# Comparar Strings pelo formato não pelo valor

Tags: c#, string, comparação

Tenho um formato de uma `String`, por exemplo:

- xxxx-xxxx-xxx

Porém, no lugar do `x` pode entrar varias letras ou números, exemplo:

- A216-0450-013
- X2LP-1018-589
- Y585-0000-047

O que preciso, fazer é comparar para saber se o formato é igual, entretanto o valor não importa.

Comment: E qual é o formato, especificamente falando? Qualquer lugar pode ter uma letra ou um número?

Comment: @jbueno sim, qualquer lugar, o formato é aquele que coloquei, 4 digitos, traço (-), 4 digitos, traço (-), 3 digitos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utilizando o `Regex.IsMatch()` você consegue verificar se uma string está dentro do padrão esperado, abaixo segue uma implementação.

---

Não se esqueça de incluir o namespace `System.Text.RegularExpressions`

> using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
string pattern = @"^.{4}-.{4}-.{3}$";
string[] input = { "A216-0450-013" , "X2LP-1018-589",   "Y585-0000-047" , "585-0000-047" };

foreach(var item in input)
{
    if(Regex.IsMatch(item,pattern))
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is Match",item);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("{0} does not Match",item);
}
```

Veja funcionando no [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rh6nuK)